# change the Json in the JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have to get data from Restful API and I want to show in the HTML by JavaScript, I have to get the data as follows:

```
function loadInfo(){
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'https://happy_ending/restful_api/propertyviewset/?format=json',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType : 'application/json',
                    }).then(function (json){
                         // on success
                        var a = JSON.stringify(json);
                        console.log(a);
                        console.log(a['data']);
                    }, function (json){
                        alert('No');
                    })
                }
```

At first, I get the data with some Messy coding, and then I add the code `var a = JSON.stringify(json);` and the Messy coding is gone, I know I have to change the JSON object to JSON string.
       the data structure is shown in the image
[image: data in the image]
Then I want to get the data according to the following ways.Unfortunately, they are both the wrong "undefined"

```
 1.console.log(a['data']); 2.console.log(a.data);
```

I have two questions :

Q1: I have set the format =json,so I just want to get the data, but In the picture，you can see, the other variables: `"status","contentType","headers","dataType"`, I want to ignore it, what can I set?

Q2: how can I get the value of "id"  in the data? I think the above two ways are both wrongs! 
Thanks in advance ~ any help is appreciated

Comment: Just don't convert the returned object to a string.

Comment: Once you have turned it into a string, you cannot access the keys with bracket or dot notation. It's no longer an object!

Comment: try JSON.parse(json) and then access it with . or []

Comment: `json.data`....

Comment: You can set `Accept` in the header as `application/json`. Like the comments above, you shouldn't have to use `JSON.stringify()` as this stringifies the json. If it were returned as a string, you can use JSON.parse() which is not the case here.

Comment: "*At first, I get the data with some Messy coding, and then I add the code 
`var a = JSON.stringify(json);` and the Messy coding is gone*" - that makes no sense. What are you talking about? As Stephen said, if you had dropped the step and just used `json.data` it would have worked